# Keras expected sequential_2 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (32, 1)

Tags: python, keras

I have build a model with keras using pre-trained VGG16

```
 model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(3, img_width, img_height)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_2'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_3'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_2'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_3'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_2'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_3'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# load the weights of the VGG16 networks
# (trained on ImageNet, won the ILSVRC competition in 2014)
# note: when there is a complete match between your model definition
# and your weight savefile, you can simply call model.load_weights(filename)
assert os.path.exists(vgg_model), 'Model weights not found (see "weights_path" variable in script).'
f = h5py.File(vgg_model)
for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
    if k >= len(model.layers):
        # we don't look at the last (fully-connected) layers in the savefile
        break
    g = f['layer_{}'.format(k)]
    weights = [g['param_{}'.format(p)] for p in range(g.attrs['nb_params'])]
    model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)
f.close()
print('Model loaded.')

# build a classifier model to put on top of the convolutional model
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

but while running the model with fit function it was throwing an exception

```
expected sequential_2 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (32, 1)
```

What was the issue here (Note: I was using the fit from directory function to train my model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in a `flow_from_directory`. You should change `class_mode = "categorical"`. Moreover - your setup for a binary classification is not usual. You should either change your final layer to:

```
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

and then leave your `loss="binary_crossentropy"` and `class_mode="binary"` in your generator or (in the second case) leave:

```
top_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

and set your `loss="categorical_crossentropy"` and `class_mode="categorical"` in your generator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your training labels.
It's hard to give an exact answer because you don't show us here the type of labels you have and the compilation you made.

I can go ahead and guess that you are compiling with either binary_crossentropy or categorical_crossentropy.

If I'm guessing correctly lets call your labels 'Y' prepare them for the training with the following code:

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y)
```

A tip: when you are doing a binary classification (two classes) you can make your last dense layer output 1 instead of 2. In your labels choose 0 for one class and 1 for the other. This way you can avoid the problem you are dealing with now.

Comment: I am using binary_crossentrophy  as per  **Y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y)** ,I am reading the data directly from directory and using [flow from directroy function](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: In that case just follow my tip and change your last dense to this:

top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

(1 instead of 2)

Comment: I want to know the probabilty of labels ,that's why i implemented softmax function

Comment: Did you try adding `class_mode='categorical'` to your flow from directory function ?